# With a USB bluetooth adapter do the devices pair with the dongle or the computer?

Tags: windows, linux, mac, usb, bluetooth

For example if you are paring a mouse and a keyboard to your Mac or PC using a USB Bluetooth adapter. Do the paired devices pair to the dongle or to the computer? Could you plug that adapter into a different nearby computer and immediately start to use those same paired devices, once the Bluetooth driver loads on that given platform.

My question arises from how is the following possible [Share your Magic Mouse between 2 machintosh computers](http://www.macgeekblog.com/blog/archive/2010/01/23/share-your-magic-mouse-between-2-machintosh-computers.html)

Answer (score 3):

The pairing is done in/by the OS, much like a USB wireless adapter connected to an access point.  You can't just move a Bluetooth mouse and USB adapter to a new machine and continue to keep the mouse working, unless that second machine also goes through the Bluetooth pairing.

Subsequent switches of the USB Bluetooth adapter back to this machine will pair with the mouse automatically.

Comment: How are they doing this, essentially sharing one Bluetooth mouse between two macs with a KVM http://www.macgeekblog.com/blog/archive/2010/01/23/share-your-magic-mouse-between-2-machintosh-computers.html

Comment: That MacGeekBlog page has the reader plug the Bluetooth USB dongle into the KVM USB mouse port.  The KVM is switching the USB data connection between two systems, both of which will have had to have the Bluetooth pairing done once.

Comment: Generally speaking can't the Bluetooth mouse be paired to only one computer at a time? Same thing for a keyboard?

Comment: That is what I understand in the general case (BT mice and keyboards only pair with a single computer at a time).  I'm assuming the KVM in the MacGeekBlog is signaling the USB changes to the dongle and computer somehow.

Comment: Yes it does not make any sense unless the unique ID for paring is a hardware ID within that dongle?

Comment: Newer versions of Bluetooth allow multiple pairings, but only one can be used at a time.  For example, my Bluetooth headset is paired both with my computer, and cell.  The headset will pair with the last device.  So if I want to use it on the computer, I disable BT on the cell.

Comment: KVMs typically emulate the mouse (and keyboard) on the host connection and emulate the USB host on at least one port (often one for the KB, and one for the mouse). This is so that (among other things) you don't need to wait for the OS to re-initialize its connection with the KB/Mouse every time you switch machines.